# How to have MySQL check and verify a static result from another column

Tags: c#, mysql

Here is my current running code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string server = "207.244.70.217";
        string database = "nextgene_NGH";
        string uid = "EXAMPLEUID";
        string password = "EXAMPLEPASSWORD";
        string ssl = "None";

        string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";    
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members && WHERE name = @name;", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
        var hashedPassword = (string) command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (!(hashedPassword is null && !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword)))
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
        }
    }
```

The above code works to login my database. The problem is it only checks to see the login name and the password. As these two work, i can't figure out how to call another column **mgroup_others** and check to see if there is a result of 7 there or not. I have attached a photo of my database here:

[image: mgroup_others]

Here is my rewritten function:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string server = "207.244.70.217";
        string database = "nextgene_NGH";
        string uid = "EXAMPLEUID";
        string password = "EXAMPLEPASSWORD";
        string ssl = "None";
        string vipcheck = "7";

        string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";    
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT members_pass_hash AND mgroup_others FROM core_members && WHERE name = @name;", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
        var hashedPassword = (string) command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (!(hashedPassword is null && !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text && vipcheck != mgroup_others, hashedPassword)))
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, progress. You should accept the answer in the bcrypt question, since you're obviously using that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to know is if the value in the `mgroup_others` column is equal to `7`, you can update your SQL as follows:

```
using var command = new MySqlCommand("""
    SELECT members_pass_hash
    FROM core_members
    WHERE name = @name AND mgroup_others = 7;
    """, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
var hashedPassword = (string) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

The advantage of this approach (compared to some other answers) is that you can still use `ExecuteScalar` because you're only reading a single value.

If you need to retrieve the value of `mgroup_others` and examine it in your C# code, you should use one of the other answers that shows how to use `ExecuteReader` or a `DataAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` clause should look like this:

```
SELECT members_pass_hash, mgroup_others
```

Then, since you are getting more than one value, you should use either `ExecuteReader()` or using a `DataAdapter` to `Fill()` a `DataTable`, so you can use all the value. If you want to have success as a developer, this is code you should write yourself, so you understand it, rather than just copying what we give you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the mentioned SQL query is wrong, so change your SELECT query as follows:

```
SELECT members_pass_hash, mgroup_others FROM core_members WHERE name = @name;
```

Refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_select.asp) doc to understand how to write proper MySql queries.

Comment: There are lots of better resources to learn SQL. The w3schools site frequently has wrong information.